# Xcode 14 project compile error：com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute

Tags: xcode14

There was no error in Xcode 13 but I am starting to get error below after upgraded to Xcode 14.This error doesn't seem to stop build from completing successfully.

error build: Dependency for P1:target-IMIHome_CN-cc573f8f295fdacea32720ac31b3c32d81d4253176a57d0d035f573833325806-:Debug:SwiftDriver Compilation Requirements IMIProject normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute (Pods/IMSThingCapability/IMSThingCapability/IMSThingCapability.framework/Modules/module.modulemap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue with some of our 3rd party libraries. Upgrading from framework to xcframework will solve the issue. If 3rd party library not providing xcframework then deleting "${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods" from "User Header Search Paths" solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got rid of the error messages by changing my modulemap file from "extern_c" to "system"

```
module ABC [system] {
...
}
```